# Can I use mSATA partly for OS and partly for Intel rapid?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, ssd

I have the following  setup now: Dell XPS 15 with 32 GB mSATA SSD and 1 TB HDD 2½ standard disk

Atm, my pc is set up with Intel Rapid  to use SSD as some kind of cache (do i get this right?) But everything is also on the 1 TB hdd.

I want to buy 250 GB mSATA ssd and replace the current 32 GB one. Then I wish to reinstall windows on the new SSD which has enough space for O S and apps now and use 1 TB as a inbuilt storage disk.

My question is: can I partition mSATA ssd into 218GB for OS and apps + 32GB for intel rapid, which would be later used again the same way the original ssd was for, i.e. "cache" for 1 TB drive.

Is this possible? How to partition the drive and when? Before reinstall, during win setup (possible?) or after OS works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some time with no answer I decided to give it a try on my own. I have come to these conslusions:

1. It is not possible to use Intel Rapid Technology on a SSD OS partition to boost any nonSSD disk
2. It is possible to set up the size of Intel Rapid "buffer" in the settings upon Enabling IRT
3. If you want to do the scenario I proposed in the question, you have to set your SSD as 2 partitions, one which would be used for OS, another one, unaccessible later for Intel Rapid.

The app can make part of existing partition available for any use when already set up, but does not know how to reformat an existing SSD to use only its part for its purposes.

Hope this helps